# Where JS stores variables declared by `let` and `const`?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, javascriptcore

An interesting question pop into my head and I couldn't find an answer, so I tried to ask you guys, to hear your thoughts about it!

Global variables that declared by `var` keyword stored as `properties` to the `window` object.

### Example

```
var foo = "foobar";
window.foo === foo;
```

This code would return `true` because the `foo` Global Variable has become a `property` to the `window` object.

**Well, the interesting part here is that:**

```
let foo = "foobar"; // Or `const` it doesn't matter
window.foo === foo;
```

That code above would return `false`.

### Shortly

I wonder; Where JavaScript store the Global Variables that declared by `let` and `const`?

Comment: In the VM memory. Btw, try to run your code with a variable named not `name` but something else, eg `foo`.

Comment: let and const are used within execution scope not global

Comment: Thanks, @zerkms for your comment. I edited the code as you requested.